# Проверка email-а в форме отправки

Tags: php

Подскажите, как мне сделать проверку email-а при отправке формы с сайта? Если я использую на странице: `action="mail.php"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой вариант выглядит как-то так:

```
$email = trim( $_POST["email"] );
$reg_test = "/^[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9\-\._]*[a-z0-9])@[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9\-]*[a-z0-9])\.[a-z0-9]+$/i";

if( empty( $email )) {
    // поле пустое
}
else if( ! preg_match( $reg_test, $email ) ) {
    // мыло имеет неверный формат
} 
else {
    // всё хорошо
}
```

Comment: СПАСИБО!!! все получилось

Answer (score 3):

[php.net/filter](http://php.net/filter)

```
$email = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
if (!$email) {
    die('Incorrect email');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[php-email-address-validation](http://code.google.com/p/php-email-address-validation/):

> A PHP class for validating email addresses according to the official specifications.

```
include('EmailAddressValidator.php');
$validator = new EmailAddressValidator;
if ($validator->check_email_address('email@domain.com')) { 
    // Почтовый адрес имеет правильную форму
} else {
    // Почтовый адрес не имеет правильной формы
}
```

Comment: Я должен создать EmailAdressValidator.php ??? Если да, то что он должен содержать???

Comment: Его надо просто скачать и расположить хотя бы в той же директории, где лежит написанная Вами страница. Качать [отсюда][1].


  [1]: http://code.google.com/p/php-email-address-validation/downloads/detail?name=EmailAddressValidator.php&can=1&q=php-email-address-validation

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="email" required />
```