# Регулярное выражение для email

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть такое регулярное выражение для проверки Email:

```
  pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\.-_]*[A-Za-z0-9]*@([A-Za-z0-9]+([A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9]+)*\.)+[A-Za-z]*$"
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не пропускает:

> my-email@ukr.net

При этом `my_email@ukr.net` и `my.email@ukr.net` пропускает.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проверка email-а в форме отправки](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/17850/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-email-%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Регулярное выражение не работает в grep](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/562760/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2-grep)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что дефис также необходимо экранировать с помощью обратного слэша:

```
pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\.\-_]
```

Так как в текущей записи `\.-_` ­знак дефиса воспринимается как знак диапазона, а не как один простой символ.

Comment: Студенты косяками пошли? :) http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/562760/Регулярное-выражение-не-работает-в-grep

Comment: @edem, можно не экранировать, если он стоит рядом со скобкой.

Comment: @Visman, да, Вы правы, можно и так.